# In selenuim webdriver - I want to select 25 check boxes with the same id for them but with different values

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenuim webdriver - I want to select 25 check boxes with the same id for them but with different values. The webpage that Im trying to automate is having 25 chexk boxes with same id as "chkDelete" with different values as below.

```
<input id="chkDelete" class="clsCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chkDelete">
<input id="chkDelete" class="clsCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="chkDelete">
<input id="chkDelete" class="clsCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="chkDelete">
```

....upto 25.

And I have tried with this code but its not working as expected.

```
if ((!driver.findElement(By.id("chkDelete")).isSelected())
    && (driver.findElement(By.id("chkDelete")).getAttribute("value") == "4")) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("chkDelete")).click();
}
```

Someone kindly help

Comment: If you have 25 elements with the **exact** same ID, you should be slapping the developers with a wet fish. How on earth have they managed to get that code passed code review? It's invalid HTML.

Comment: Do not post the HTML in the comments. Update your question with it instead.

Comment: @Arran : thats right,all check boxes are having different values in them..cant we use that..?

Comment: An `id` by its definition should be unique. If the developers are not using unique `id`s then there is near no point in using `id`s for elements. As it is they are providing a unique value attribute which is different but works here. See below for an answer on clicking the element with the value = 4.

Comment: @MarkRowlands Thanks, can you show me sample code pls

Comment: @MuthuKumar : 'id' attributes in HTML is used to differentiate HTML elements. If you are using same ID for all the checkbox. Then how can you access those checkbox elements ?

Comment: It is very bad development. Actually you want to check all the 25 check box or to check the check box with value `4`. Your question and the pasted code are not correlate each other.

Comment: I want to select more than one check box, I meant to say that each check boxes are having same id but different values as I given in code sample

Comment: I tried below code and it worked.List<WebElement> boxes = driver.findElements(By.id("chkDelete"));
   System.out.println(boxes.size());
   for(WebElement box : boxes) {    
       if(box.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {        
           if(!box.isSelected()) {
               box.click();
           }
       }
   }

Comment: Thanks a lot for all responses..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the checkbox with the value 4 as per your example:

```
List<WebElement> boxes = driver.findElements(By.Id("chkDelete"));
for(WebElement box : boxes) {
    if(box.getAttribute("value") == "4") {
        if(!box.isSelected()) {
            box.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code :

```
List <WebElement> deleteCheckbox = driver.findElements(By.id("chkDelete"));

for(WebElement checkDelete : deleteCheckbox)
{

   if(!checkDelete.isSelected())
   {
      checkDelete.click();
   }

}
```